# Adding a single post template from a plugin level

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently working on a plugin for a website and I have a need to add a template to a custom post type from the plugin level without changing the theme files. Since single-posttype.php method does not work inside a plugin I've tried to add the template manually using the "add_filter" wordpress hook however I can't get it to work. Here are the functions I'm using to register the template:

```
public function templateArray()
{
    $temps = [];
    $temps['customTemplate.php'] = 'Entry Template';
    return $temps;
}

public function templateRegister($single_templates, $theme, $post)
{
    $templates = templateArray();

    foreach($templates as $tk=>$tv)
    {
        $single_templates[$tk] = $tv;
    }
    return $single_templates;
}
```

I'm applying the filter like this:

```
add_filter('single_template', 'templateRegister', 10, 3);
```

The project also uses Twig if that's important.

I'm quite new to wordpress development so if something seems obvious, I probably don't know it. :D